# highcharts not given the right xAxis labels on page load

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having what appears to be a highcharts sizing issue. The width of the highcharts svg, and the containing div are the same, and they are sizing correctly (going from 525px to 530px when I bump the window). However the labels act correct after the resize, but not on page load.

Here's what the chart looks like on page load:

[image: highcharts page load]

You can see the issue with the xAxis labels.

and after I size the window BIGGER (manually with my mouse):

[image: highcharts on resize]

note that I am using angularjs and the angularjs highcharts directive found here: 
https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng. I don't think that's related however.

any help you can provide is much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: What's your expected output on load, though? You should probably show the configuration code of the chart.

Comment: I expect it to look like what it does after I resize it a mere 5 pixels. I'll get a fiddle working to show the problem.

Comment: If you find a solution, don't hesitate to answer your own question ;)

Comment: You can set [tickPixelInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPixelInterval) or [tickInterval](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickInterval) parameters to keep regular distance between ticks.

Comment: thank you that solved it, highcharts must not be able to detect additional label format lengths like the % added here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the labels overlap and Highcharts removes them automatically. I suggest you to give a look at the [Highcharts API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels).

> Overflow
>
> How to handle overflowing labels on horizontal axis. Can be undefined,
>   false or "justify". By default it aligns inside the chart area. If
>   "justify", labels will not render outside the plot area. If false, it
>   will not be aligned at all. If there is room to move it, it will be
>   aligned to the edge, else it will be removed.

Changing the `overflow` property to "justify" may fix it, but it may not look good. Give it a try.

Another suggestion to fix this, is to give it a fixed size of lines to display the labels, with the `staggerLines` property. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/labels-staggerlines/) and see it fits to your problem.

Comment: thanks for the insight. The labels actually look great...after I resize the window. They are acting as if they have more space then they do. In the first picture you can see it thinks it has room for decimals: 2.5, 5, 7.5, 10... but when I size the window (even if I size it bigger) it realizes it does not have the room it thought it had on page load and fixes them to 0, 10, 20, 30..

Comment: So, what's your goal? To make the labels appear 0, 10, 20, 30... on load?

Comment: I think highcharts thinks it's a width it's not and as a result is putting in all these extra labels. When I resize the window, it triggers highcharts to recalculate the look of the chart and it at that point gets the chart size correctly and outputs the appropriate amount of labels. In this case, the appropriate amount gets it to 0, 10, 20, 30

Comment: @user3455992 Well, then I don't know. All I can suggest you is to try `setSize()`, `reflow()` or `redraw` in `Charts`. It's a try-error situation.